# how to solve "expected statement {"

Tags: c

```
bool vote(string name)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
   {
       candidates[i].votes ++;
       return true;
       printf("yay");
   }
      while (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) 
}




~/workspace/pset3/plurality/ $ make plurality
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    plurality.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o plurality
plurality.c:77:1: error: expected statement
}
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: plurality] Error 1
```

Why does it keep saying "expected statement {" I have the bracket where it needs to be. Am I writing something wrong.

Comment: What are you expecting the `while` statement to do? Is it syntactically correct?

Comment: The `while` loop is expecting a statement. `while(...) { // do something }`.

Comment: With the new code, what is returned if none of the candidates have matching names (so the `for` loop completes)?

Comment: @NateEldredge yep adding a `return false;` like my answer below does should fix that issue.

Comment: SO is not an incremental syntax-corrector/debugger.  Your edits are rendering comments and answers confusing for present and future users:(  Rolled back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't return anything if the for loop finishes.

```c
bool vote(string name)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
   {
       if(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
       {
           candidates[i].votes ++;
           return true;
           printf("yay");
       }
       
   }
   return false;  
}
```

---

BEFORE EDIT:
You have an syntactically invalid while loop on the last line in your function.

In C, while loops can have an empty body but they must be in one of the following formats:

K&R uses this all the time:

```c
while(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0);
```

Some others prefer to use the brackets with nothing inside, as such:

```c
while(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) 
{
}
```

Others prefer the semicolon to go on a separate line, to reinforce the fact that it's a loop:

```c
while(strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
  ;
```

All are valid - you'll just have to pick the style you like and stick with it.

Alternatively, you could remove the statement entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
  while (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
```

What should be executed when this condition is true? You should have something like:

```
while (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)  {
// some code here that happens when this condition is true
}
```

Basically, same as what you're doing with the for-loop. It's expecting the brackets for the while-loop or a statement.